# Null Reference Exception On Constructor

Tags: c#, dll, .net-standard

I am consuming a .net standard project in another .net standard project. I packaged it up as a nuget package and included the dll inside my project. When my project calls into the dll to do some work, it first news up an object

```
var account = new Data.Account();
```

Where the Account class looks as follows:

```
internal class Account : Base
{
    const string NAME = "test";

    internal Account() { }
}
```

And the base class looks as followed:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected string connectionString;

    public Base()
    {
        connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

However when it tries to new up this class it throws an exception:

```
   at xxx.xx.Data.Base..ctor() in xxx\xxx\Data\Base.cs:line 11
```

Where line 11 is simply the `public Base()` constructor

I have included the pdb in the nuspec file so that I can debug into the dll but doing so provides no additional context or strack trace. I am starting to think that it either has to do with the classes being internal or it is not finding the connectionstring key in the app.config in the dll, that is what I have now been researching online.

Comment: "not finding the connectionstring key" - Bingo.  Debugging should confirm this.

Comment: My guess is that it cannot find the connection string

Comment: @Brian Debugging wasn't even stepping into Account or Base when I was newing up an Account. For reference, this .net standard that calls the dll is part of a web api solution and so in my .net core web api for startup ive included connectionstring in the appsettings.json with no luck. I've also tried adding an app.config with the connection string to the .net standard project that calls the dll

Comment: you should really pass the connectionstring in as a parameter to "Base".  Then you will be forced at compile time to provide it, rather than runtime errors like you are encountering.

Comment: Most likely `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"]` is null because you haven't added the configuration item in the _executing_ app's config, not the _library's_ config.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks. I have added a ConnectionStrings section to the appsettings.json of the consuming app with a connectionstring key/value pair, but it still doesn't seem to be finding that when it calls ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` in a .NET Core 2.0 application, you need to add an App.config to the project (in your case the ASP.NET Core WebApi project) with the relevant configuration sections.
2. You should check for null when reading configuration settings, so you can handle it gracefully with a more meaningful error message, e.g.

   ```
   var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
       .ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"]?.ConnectionString;
   if (connectionString == null)
   {
        throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(
           "ConnectionString 'connectionString' not found in application configuration file"
           );
   }
   ```

Comment: The dll is calling ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings in a .net standard project, whereas my web api is a .net core. So in appsettings.json i've added a ConnectionStrings section with connectionstring key/value pair. However this doesn't solve it and i'm not sure that when the dll calls ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings it knows what to do since it is .net core and does not have an app.config

Comment: .NET Core 2.0 does support app.config - try it!  It replaces (or complements) appsettings.json.  A bit confusing I know, but since .NET Standard has to work on both .Net Framework and .NET Core, a common format for configuration is needed, hence the move back to XML configuration,